# iCarousel with UITableView swiping issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, icarousel

[image]

this is code snippet.

```
carousel.delegate = self;
carousel.dataSource = self;
carousel.decelerationRate = 0.7;
carousel.type = iCarouselTypeLinear;
carousel.pagingEnabled = YES;
carousel.edgeRecognition = YES;
carousel.bounceDistance = 0.4;
carousel.scrollSpeed = 2;
carousel.clipsToBounds = YES;

- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    MyProjectView *projectView = [[MyProjectView alloc] init];
    projectView.frame = carousel.bounds;
    [projectView bindData];

    return projectView;
}
```

MyProjectView is a subclass of `UITableView`.Look at the pic,I swipe iCarousel and stop my finger in the middle, when I up my finger,the view can't scroll and stop in the screen middle.I don't know how to fix this bug.

Comment: Which type of behavior you want?

Comment: thank you for your reply

Comment: Thank you for your reply,like the describe above.I swipe it and stop my finger in the middle of screen, when I lift my finger and tap the screen quickly, and the iCarousel stop scroll,then I lift my finger again it may auto scroll.But in fact,it can't scroll no longer.I want it scroll when I lift my finger the second time.